# UITableView not loading fully inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm creating a ViewController that will contain as a portion of it a scrollView. In that scrollView I would like to include the view of another ViewController. When I set up this ViewController inside of the ScrollView, all of that ViewController's data is pulled from the web and even it's "ViewDidLoad" method is called. However, nothing appears except for the tableViewLines and a spinner I've created to show the page is loading. Here is what it looks like (the ScrollView in question is under Commitments and Awards):

[image: See here.]

What should be loaded inside the scrollView is a tableView that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why are you adding a UITableView inside a UIScrollView?  A tableView with a frame size smaller than its contentSize will have its content scrolling.  Unless you want to display multiple tableViews side by side, you should add the tableView directly to the view.

Comment: My end goal is not to add a TableView. I just want it done so that when I build my actual view I will be using, I could add it no-problem.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your goal then.  If you only want to display a list of elements under a descriptive "title view", I'd suggest to only use a full screen tableView with some custom view as the ```tableViewHeader```.

Comment: My goal is mainly an exercise. I don't actually want that tableView within the scroll view in the final app. I would like to know how to get it to appear there, however, because I will be doing something similar to this later on.

Comment: Could the problem be that it's inside a UIScrollView (it didn't work when I tried a UIView either) and not a child View Controller? If so, IB doesn't let me add child View Controller's--only Storyboard, and I'm not using Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the tableview's delegate/datasource are not set correctly.  Could you check whether `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are called or not?

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good idea to show view of one view controller in another view controller view. Apple does not recommend it. what ever you want to do, do it in the same view controller.

Comment: That is false.  A UIViewController can have childViewControllers, and even has specific methods to handle them.  In fact, a UINavigationController is just that, a UIViewController containing one or more child UIViewControllers (whose views are added in the parent view).

Comment: A navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller can have references to multiple view controllers, but they are not child view controllers as you are thinking. There is difference between a view and a view controller. A view controller owns a view, only its own view controller should handle a view, not other view controllers.

Comment: Taken from Apple's UIViewController documentation: ```If the view controller is owned by another view controller, then the parent view controller determines when and how the child view controller’s contents are displayed.```.  I suggest reading the section titled "Implementing a Container View Controller" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/

Comment: Yes, both the statement and I are right, a view controller can own another view controller. So, parent view controller determines the size of the child view controller's view. But a parent view controller can not have direct link to child view controllers view. If you read it one more time, keeping my point in view, you will understand it.

Comment: Adding viewCtrlA.view as a subview of viewCtrlB.view (using ```addSubview:```) doesn't change viewCtrlA's ownership of its view.  Here's [another Apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).  Among other things, the UINavigationController's hierarchy is explained: ```The topmost view controller’s view is placed in the navigation controller’s view hierarchy``` (an example of a controller's view shown in another controller's view).

Comment: I don't know, but I think, that iKrish is talking about subviews of the main view of child viewcontroller... say, a UIViewController has the main view and within it is a UIButton. I think iKrish says, parent viewcontroller should not have access to that child's viewcontrollers UIButton. I may be wrong, but this is how I understand iKrish's comment. That of course makes sense. Of course when we're talking about the MAIN view of the view controller, then the parent controller decides when and where the child viewcontroller's view is displayed. That also is a true statement.